# How to make opacity darker in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My main window backgrond color is `Background="#005075"` when the user click on some button some small window pops up, and then I'm chanching the main window opacity like `Opacity="0.5"`, the problem is that it makes the background lighter, how do I make a dark opcity in wpf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opacity will not make it darker. What you can do is you can make some kind of panel which is stretched all over your main window, and has a black color and opacity of 0.2 or something like that, and mainly is hidden by default. And when you want to make the main window disabled you make that panel visible. This should solve your problem.

You can also use it as a loading panel, if you add some animation in center or something like this. So it will be over all of the content of your main window and will not allow the user to interact with your main window while it's disabled.

P.S. The black panel with opacity 0.2 should be positioned over all of the controls in main window

Answer (score 3):

I do something similar a lot. The best way to do this is by having a couple of top-level grid's in your Window and work with those rather than the Window itself.

For example, Ill do something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp9.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp9"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <!-- Background grid with 100% opacity -->
        <Grid Background="#005075"/>
        <!-- main grid, which sits on top of the background grid -->
        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Background="Transparent" Opacity="0.5">
            <!-- Windows controls go here -->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: This way you can even change the theme with one click :-)